# How to cover block catch by JUnit

Tags: java, junit, try-catch

I want to cover the `catch` sections of this `try` block with JUnit. How do I do it?

```
public class ClientCertSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientCertSocketFactory.class);

    private SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

    public ClientCertSocketFactory() throws IOException{
        String trustStoreFilePath = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = CertManagerFactory.loadTrustStore(trustStoreFilePath);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            this.sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("No Provider supports a TrustManagerFactorySpi implementation for the TLS protocol. Error message: " + e);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred when initializing SSLContext. Error message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the init method throw these different errors or mock trustManagerFactory and make trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers() throw these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First of all, catching exceptions and doing nothing but logging them is a Code Smell. Read this article, for example.](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html)

That being said, it is *also* a Code Smell when you call these creation methods like:

- `CertManagerFactory.loadTrustStore`
- `SSLContext.getInstance`

Inside the constructor, instead of passing them in. If you were to use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead, you could pass these objects into the constructor and see if the constructor works the way you want it to.